# Remove commas from input text in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, user-input

Can anyone tell me how to implement, a split maybe? To remove commas from user input text numbers before running some if statements. I know I can restrict commas, but I'd like people to be able to use commas when imputing values. Thanks!

```
value_enter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, release1);
function release1(evt:MouseEvent):void 
{
if ( Number(inputfield.text) >0 &&  Number(inputfield.text) <2600)
{
gotoAndStop(2);
}
else if ( Number(inputfield.text) >2599 &&  Number(inputfield.text) <4200)
{
gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
value_enter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, release1);
function release1(evt:MouseEvent):void 
{
    var strNum:String = String(inputfield.text).replace(/,/g, "");
    var num:Number = Number(strNum);

    if ( num > 0 &&  num <2600)
    {
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    else if ( num >2599 &&  num <4200)
    {
        gotoAndStop(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be better to use `/[^0-9]/g` instead, since not everyone uses commas as a thousands separator.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `replace()` function:

```
inputfield.text = inputfield.text.replace(",", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to remove all instances you can do a split like you were thinking:

if your `inputfield.text = "123,456,789";`

then:

```
var inputNoCommas:String = inputfield.text.split(",").join("");
```

should return `"123456789";

As I recall [String.replace()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29) only replaces the first instance, which if that is all you want then you can go that route.